# SQL Server LIMIT 1 and LIMIT 1,1 syntax error

Tags: sql-server, limit

Interestingly enough I found no post for this specific, but basic issue.

Goal: update the latest budgetid record docstatus = 0. Then I want to update the *next-to-last* budgetid record docstatus = 1. I am trying this within PHP but also testing in my SQL Server SEM and it is failing there, too.

My SQL Server statement:

```
select 
    budgetid, docstatus, datechanged 
from 
    ccy_budget 
where 
    activityid = 11111 
order by 
    datechanged desc 
limit 1,1;
```

Error that occurs in SEM is:

> Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.

Yet in w3schools this [sample] sql works just fine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
ORDER BY postalcode DESC 
LIMIT 1,1;
```

Seems so simple, surely I am missing something fundamental.

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) 
Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: `limit 1` is mysql syntax. You want `select top 1` in sql server

Comment: Yep SQL server <> mySQL.   2008 doesn't support this concept.  2012+ does using [offset fetch](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx)  Sadly not all SQL is the same  T-SQL, PL\SQL, mySQL, Postgresql, sybase, dB2... they all have their own functions variations.

Comment: Where in the [SQL Server manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741(v=sql.105).aspx) did you find `limit`?

Comment: horse - here is 1 among others i found, and so thought it would be legal to use limit:  [www] techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php

Comment: simon - "top 1" works to get the top one. i want the next to top one. perhaps i can try grabbing 2 records; then if #rows >= 2 then grabbing the second one? looking at example below someone posted, too.

Comment: @dcparham Did you read the tip? _For databases such as **SQL Server** or MSAccess, use the **SELECT TOP** statement to limit your results. The SELECT TOP statement is Microsoft's proprietary equivalent to the SELECT LIMIT statement._

Comment: @dcparham So this is kind of tricky because you asked a 2 in 1 question. One about syntax and the other about updating based on order. In the future I recommend posting two questions: First question being _I got this syntax error and here's what I tried_, then posting a second question _here's what I tried, not getting desired results on update_.

Comment: Just my 2 cents, I think w3schools is a great site for purely _reference_. I don't think it's a great place for those learning or unfamiliar with sql. If you want to play around with examples try creating your own tables and playing with them in sql fiddle or rextester.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equivalent syntax in SQL Server would be

```
select * 
from table
order by somerow desc
offset 1 rows fetch next 1 rows only;
```

But the above is available from SQL Server 2012 on, so for your version, you have to some thing like below

```
;with cte
as
(
select *,row_number() over (order by postalcode desc) as rn
from table
)
select * from cte where rn=2
```

Comment: if 2012+  if 2008 as in question don't think this would work.

Comment: war - your code looked weird to me but i tried exactly that and it is boomshokalaka working! thank you much!! i will stuff it into a sql var in my php as such ===> ";with cte as (select *,row_number() over (order by datechanged desc) as rn from budget_table where activitynum=11111) select * from cte where rn=2"

Comment: Glad it helped you